# Include header of CMake targets in a object library

Tags: c++, cmake, conan

**Scenario:**

I'm porting an applications build system to CMake. Dependencies are already installed on the system or will be handled via conan.

Lets say the project is structured as following:

```
- include/
  - BigFoo/
    - *.hpp
- src/
  - BigFoo/
    - *.cpp
  - main.cpp
  - *.qml
- test/
  - BigFoo/
    - *Test.cpp
```

My goal is to reuse the compilation output (*.o) of BigFoo in the main application and the unit tests. I don't want an internal library (*.a or *.so) for BigFoo.

BigFoo is using Qt5 and Boost components from the target system. It also uses components provided as conan packages.

**Current approach:**

- Build BigFoo as static library => handle dependencies via target_link_library()
- Build main.cpp and *.qml => link with BigFoo
- Build BigFoo/*Test.cpp => link with BigFoo

**Desired approach:**

- Build BigFoo as object library => include dependency headers
- Build main.cpp, *.qml with BigFoo_Object => link dependencies
- Build BigFoo/*Test.cpp with BigFoo_Object => link dependencies

**Problem of the desired approach:**

I could not include dependency headers of several components (Boost::XYZ Qt5::XYZ CONAN_PKG::XYZ etc) via target_include_directories() when building an OBJECT library.

```
add_library(Core OBJECT)

# I want to do something like this:
target_include_directories(Core PUBLIC 
    Qt5::Core
    Qt5::Qml
    Qt5::Quick
    Qt5::Scxml
    CONAN_PKG::XYZ
    CONAN_PKG::XYZ
)
```

The result is CMake (of course) adds header include paths like the following...

```
-I../../../Application/Qt5::Qml
```

And fails later because it cannot dismantle Qt include statements.

When building a static lib the header include was handled by target_link_libraries(), I'm now a bit confussed how to do this on a OBJECT library where I do not link anything.

**My Questions:**

1. How can I include headers of CMake targets provided by find_package() and CONAN_PKG in a OBJECT library target?
2. Is there is a better/nicer way of reusing BigFoo so i don't have duplicated compilation?

PS: I'm using cmake 3.13

Comment: Your desired approach seems reasonable, but you need to be more specific with "I could not include". Why? Was there any errors? During compilation or CMake configuration? Also, which CMake version do you use, `OBJECT` libraries have much better support in newer releases.

Comment: have you included conan_basic_setup(TARGETS) in your CMakeLists.txt? CONAN_PKG is only exported if you chose TARGETS

Comment: Thank you for the hint, I've updated the question.

Comment: Yes, I'm using the TARGETS flag on conan_basic_setup. I also checked the generated conan *.cmake file. All requiered dependencies are exported as INTERFACE + IMPORTED lib.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know that this seems nonsense, because object libraries aren't linked at all. But that is only one of the awkwardness of the CMake object libraries. This is what you probably need:

```
add_library(Core OBJECT)

target_link_libraries(Core PUBLIC 
    Qt5::Core
    Qt5::Qml
    Qt5::Quick
    Qt5::Scxml
    CONAN_PKG::XYZ
    CONAN_PKG::XYZ
)
```

[Object libraries may be used as the target (first) argument of target_link_libraries to specify dependencies of their sources on other libraries](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_libraries.html#linking-object-libraries).

Comment: Thank you! I would have never expected that this functionallity is part of a function named "link" in context of object libraries. For others: this adds all include directories from the passed targets to the compile command with "-isystem"

Comment: You are welcome. And target_link_libraries() adds the include directories of the imported targets always, not only for object libraries. You can avoid target_include_directories() for executables and shared libraries too, when your dependencies are imported targets.

Comment: How do you do this on CMake 3.10, the one that ships with Ubuntu 18.04, where `target_link_libraries` isn't yet allowed to apply to an object library?